# How do I change the url of my IIS hosted site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Currently, my .NET MVC application hosted on IIS 7 can be accessed remotely with the following url:

http://172.21.1.83:8080/Mysite/Index

I want to be able to use the url 
http://example.com/Mysite/Index instead.

How do I achieve this? Basically I just want to get rid of the ip address and port number in the url, and replace it with a custom domain name (like example.com).

Comment: Change the bindings...

Comment: Add `example.com` as host name in IIS site bindings.

Comment: Is it on a different server? Why are you directing to 8080?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a reverse proxy. That way the user doesn't have to see or use the port. Check out this article.

http://www.myconnectionserver.com/support/tutorials/v90/iisProxy/index.html

Answer (score 0):

In your IIS web application click on **Bidings** from the right side menu bar, and add a new biding by entering your IP address and Port number, and your Host Name as the domain name which in your example is http://example.com/Mysite/Index.

[image]